# javascript/jQuery making multiple calls - need to figure out why

Tags: jquery

I have a script that calculates a price via jQuery ajax and I'm noticing in the Firebug console that the same ajax GET call is happening multiple (sometimes dozens) of times. I'm using a mix of javascript and jQuery to kick off the function and I have a feeling this is the issue. I just don't know a more efficient way to do it.

The function runs when a value is selected from a menu. Here is the code for that:

```
<div id="order_promo">
<select name="promo1" id="promo1" onmouseover="CalcPromo(1)">
<option value="1">Name1</option
.....
.....
</select>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript/jQuery function:

```
function CalcPromo(row){
      $(function(){
         $('#promo' + row).change(function(){
                //values to pass to php script for calculations

                var promo=$(this).val();
                var id=$('#item' + row).val();
                var qty=$('#qty' + row).val();
                var price=$('#price' + row).val();

                var dataString = 'prodid='+ id + '&qty=' + qty + '&price=' + price + '&promo=' + promo + '&type=promo' + '&row=' + row ; //string passed to url
                $.ajax
                ({
                    url: "includes/ajax/orders2.php", //url of php script
                    dataType: 'json', //json is return type from php script
                    data: dataString, //dataString is the string passed to the url
                    success: function(pricedata) //pricedata is the name of json array that is returned
                    {
                        //individual values from json array
                        var listprice = pricedata["price"];
                        var disc = pricedata["disc"];
                        var total = pricedata["total"];
                        var tax = pricedata["tax"];
                        var grand = pricedata["grand"];

                        //set each value using text box id value using javascript val() function
                        $('#price' + row).val(listprice);
                        $('#discprice' + row).val(disc);
                        $('#itemprice' + row).val(total);
                        $("#tax").val(tax);
                        $("#grandtotal").val(grand);
                     },
                     error: function(request, status, error)
                     {
                         alert(request.responseText);
                     }
            });

        });

    });
    }
```

The function should kick off when a value is selected from the menu "promo1". This was the only way I could make it work. I'm assuming their is a pure jQuery way to do this and eliminate the multiple calls. This is where I'm struggling.

Thanks!

Comment: EVERY time you do a mouseover (from your markup) it adds a new handler: `function CalcPromo(row){
      $(function(){
         $('#promo' + row).change(function(){`

Comment: Do you have multiple `<select` or just the one?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Ahhh...ok that makes sense. Yes, three total.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I changed it and it worked correctly. Is it possible for you to post an answer so I can award you points?

Answer (score 2):

EVERY time you do a mouseover (from your markup) it adds a new handler:

```
function CalcPromo(row){ 
    $(function(){
        $('#promo' + row).change(function(){
```

should be something like:

```
$(function(){
     $('select[id^="promo"]').change(function(){
```

You will need to get a "row" - which MIGHT be and index of the selects?  Don't have your markup to evaluate that:

```
var row = $(this).index('select');
```

Remove the behavior from your markup:

```
<select name="promo1" id="promo1" onmouseover="CalcPromo(1)">
```

Becomes

```
<select name="promo1" id="promo1">
```

alternate would be to add either a class to the markup OR better a data element:

```
<select name="promo1" id="promo1" class="myselectorclass" data-row="1">
```

THEN row becomes one of these:

```
var row = $(this).data("row");// use this one
// OR
var row = $(this).index('.myselectorclass');
```

and your event could be:

```
$('.myselectorclass').change(function(){
```

Comment: As you are fairly new to SO, IF this works, and you get no better answers you should click the check mark to the left of the answer. Not that I am asking for reputation, but only that this marks the answer as accepted and makes it easier for people looking for questions without accepted answers to help people.